# Save splitting videos into database and retrieve them

Tags: c#, .net, database, video, encoding

I am working with the Microsoft encoder to split video's. This is the example from the Microsoft website:

```
MediaItem item = new MediaItem(@"C:\myvideo.wmv");
item.SourceClips[0].EndTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15);

TimeSpan timeStart = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
TimeSpan timeEnd = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 45);
item.SourceClips.Add(new SourceClip(timeStart, timeEnd));
```

Is there a way that I can save the splitting video's into a database? And is it possible to GET the splitting video's from the database to the client side?

Source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/deanro/2009/03/16/editing-files-with-encoder/

Kind regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this.

1. You upload the video files directly into your DB (You need a `BLOB` field in your database's video table)
2. You save your video files on the filesystem and store the paths to those files inside the database (preferred).

**Why do I prefer the second approach?** 
Databases are designed to handle small objects very, very fast. On the other hand larger objects inside the database degrade over time, access speeds suffer. The second approach is also more trivial but let's get to the first.

**Encoding:**

```
private void Encode()
{
    Job j = new Job();
    MediaItem m = new MediaItem(txtBxVideoFilePath.Text);
    Source s = m.Sources[0];
    s.Clips[0].StartTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
    s.Clips[0].EndTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
    j.OutputDirectory= @"C:\Users\MyOutputDir\";
    j.MediaItems.Add(m);
    j.Encode();
    txtBxOutputDir.Text = j.ActualOutputDirectory; //Path to your videofile
}
```

After the encoding you'll get a directory string in your `Job`'s `ActualOutputDirectory` which you can access then to get your encoded video files, either save them elsewhere (second approach) or save them as a `BLOB` inside your db.

Storing as `(LONG)BLOB` (in my case I use `MySQL` as my DBMS, but other DBMS shouldn't be too different):

Creating the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `video` (
  `VideoID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `VideoName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `VideoSize` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `VideoFile` longblob NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Of course there's much missing e.g indexes, primary keys but that's not relevant to get the overall idea.

To store the file inside your DB you have to read it as a BLOB compatible object, which is a byte array (`byte[]`).

```
byte[] video = File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
```

You can get the filepath by iterating through the `ActualOutputDirectory`:

```
foreach (string filepath in Directory.GetFiles(ActualOutputDirectory))
{
   StoreBLOBInDB(filepath);
}
```

The code of inserting your video file into a DB may look like this:

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("", connection);
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO video (VideoName, VideoSize, VideoFile) VALUES (?videoname, ?videosize, ?videofile);";

byte[] video = File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);

MySqlParameter pVideoName= new MySqlParameter("?videoname", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
pVideoName.Value = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
MySqlParameter pVideoSize = new MySqlParameter("?videosize", MySqlDbType.Int32);
pVideoSize.Value = video.Length;
MySqlParameter pVideoBlob= new MySqlParameter("?videofile", MySqlDbType.Blob, video.Length);
pVideoBlob.Value = video;

command.Parameters.Add(pVideoName);
command.Parameters.Add(pVideoSize);
command.Parameters.Add(pVideoBlob);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Opening/Closing of the connection:

```
string myConnectionString = "SERVER=localhost;" +
                         "DATABASE=encodingdb;" +
                         "UID=encoder;" +
                         "PASSWORD=encoder;";
this.connection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
this.connection.Open();

this.connection.Close();
```

The retrieval of the file BLOB is also quite easy:

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("", connection);
command.CommandText = "SELECT VideoName, VideoSize, VideoFile FROM video WHERE VideoName=?videoname;";
MySqlParameter pVideoname = new MySqlParameter("?videoname", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
pVideoname.Value = Path.GetFileName(videoName);
command.Parameters.Add(pVideoname);
MySqlDataReader videofileReader;
videofileReader = command.ExecuteReader();
byte[] videoBlob = new byte[0];
while (videofileReader.Read())
{
    int videoSize = videofileReader.GetInt32("VideoSize");
    videoBlob = new byte[videoSize];
    videofileReader.GetBytes(videofileReader.GetOrdinal("VideoFile"), 0, videoBlob, 0, videoSize);
}
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Encoding\export.wmv", videoBlob);
videofileReader.Close();
CloseConnection();
```

Comment: Thank you for your time! This is exactly what I want and have a nice day.

Comment: You're welcome, have a nice day, too. Happy coding :-)

Comment: In MSSQL you could use FileStreams for saving the blob data. FILESTREAM integrates the SQL Server Database Engine with an NTFS file system by storing varbinary(max) binary large object (BLOB) data as files on the file system.  See more details here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993(v=sql.105).aspx